# Changing the background colour of a child window C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I have created a child window within the main window and I wish to set the colour of the main window to red and the colour of the child window to blue.  I have tried a number of ways but each time the parent window becomes the same colour as the child window.  Below is the code:

```
hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
  400, 170, 500, 500, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0));
box1 = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST, szWindowClass, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER,475, 475, 25, 25, hWnd, (HMENU)10001, hInstance, NULL);
SetClassLongPtr(box1, GCLP_HBRBACKGROUND,(LONG) brush );

brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 0));
SetClassLongPtr(hWnd, GCLP_HBRBACKGROUND,(LONG) brush );
```

Answer (score 2):

`SetClassLongPtr` changes the setting for the entire window class, so all windows in this class are affected. Since both your windows use the same `szWindowClass`, they share the same class brush.

Try creating a separate window class for the child window. Alternatively you can handle the [`WM_ERASEBKGND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648055%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message to paint the background yourself.

Comment: when I try to create a separate window class, the window using the new class doesn't show.